# Async/Await throw an error in Mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, async-await, mocha.js

I'm trying to catch an error which should be throw by the function `getUserRecommendations`. This is my example:

```
it('should throw an error when no user ID is provided', (done) => {
  expect(async () => {
    await Client.getUserRecommendations(null, {})
  }).to.throw(/Missing/)
})
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I get as result that my test it doesn't pass along with this message:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error
```

Comment: Please don't edit solutions into the question, rather [post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Notice that the `async`/`await` here is totally useless. `expect(() => SClient.getUserRecommendations(null, {}))` uses a function that returns a promise just as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you have set up the the test won't work because `expect.to.throw` is not expecting a promise.  At least I think that is what is going on based on [this issue](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/415).

The best alternative is to use `chai-as-promised` and do something like:

```
it('should throw an error when no user ID is provided', () => {
  expect(Client.getUserRecommendations(null, {})).be.rejectedWith(/Missing/);
});
```

Comment: I've edited by using `chai-as-promised` but now I get this error:      TypeError: [Function] is not a thenable.

Comment: don't use `async` and `await` keywords in the `expect`. chai-as-promised will handle the underlying promise.

Comment: @Mazzy does `Client.getUserRecommendations()` actually return a promise?

Comment: Yes `getUserRecommendations` is an async/await function so it should return a promise